# Como habilitar y desabilitar un boton en React Native y al deshabilitarlo ponerlo de un color distinto

Tags: react-native

Quisiera saber como habilito y des habilito un botón y como al des habilitarlo le cambio el color .

```
<TouchableOpacity  disabled={disabled} onPress={() =>   navigation.navigate("ReviewOrder",{quantityOrders:screenProps.quantityOrders})}>
        <View style={styles.circleOrder}>
          <Text style={styles.labelNroOrder}>{screenProps.quantityOrders}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>: null
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> puede que esto te funcione

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         disabled: true
      };
   }

   funciona() {
      console.log('yey! :3');
   }

   habilitarBoton() {
      this.state.disabled === true ?
        this.setState({disabled: false})
        :this.setState({disabled: true});
   }

   render() {
      let colorDelBoton = [{backgroundColor: this.state.disabled === false ? '#face34' : 'gray'}];
      return (<View>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.habilitarBoton()}>
            <Text>Habilitar el otro boton</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity style={colorDelBoton} onPress={() => this.state.disabled === false ?this.funciona() :null}>
            <Text>Otro boton</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>);
   }
```

Comment: Trata de agregar la explicación de que utilidad tiene y como implementarlo, pues al momento tu respuesta es de baja calidad saludos